# Abundant Number Test

Tags: c++, loops, menu, numbers

A natural number n > 0 is said to be an abundant number if the sum of its proper divisors (including 1 but excluding n itself) is greater than itself.  For example, the number 12 is an abundant number because the sum of its divisors (including 1 but excluding 12 itself) is 1+2+3+4+6=16, which is greater than 12 itself. As a contrast, the number 6 is NOT an abundant number because the sum of its divisors (including 1 but excluding 6 itself) is 1+2+3=6, which is NOT greater than 6 itself. See more examples and explanation here.

It seems as if every time the user inputs a number, it is always abundant. Any suggestions on what needs to be done?

```
    // If the user selects option "a"
    if (option == 'a')
    {
        bool abundantTest(int n);
        {
            int n, i = 1, sum = 0;
            cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
            cin >> n;

            while (i < n){
                    if (n % i == 0)
                        sum = sum + i;
                        i++;
            }

            if (sum == n){
                cout << i << " is not an abundant number." << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << i << " is an abundant number." << endl;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want to check

```
if (sum <= n)
```

***Less or equal to* is the opposite of *greater than***.

You could also have:

```
if (sum > n)
    cout << i << " is an abundant number." << endl;
else
    cout << i << " is not an abundant number." << endl;
```

And briefly:

```
cout << i << " is " + std::string(sum > n ? "" : "not ") + "an abundant number." << endl;
```